# Could not allocate dup blob fd : IconGenerator with thousand markers causes exception

Tags: google-maps, markerclusterer, android-maps-utils

My app have 1,5 thousand markers, showed throught marker clustering.

Actually it works fine with default markers, but i want do use vector bitmap and render markers with text (price of gas station), like this:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Before finishing rendering markers, occurs this exception: "Could not allocate dup blob fd."

I think it's some kind of memory overflow, but I do not know how to solve it.
Does anyone have any idea how to solve this problem or have another suggestion of how to manage so many markers?

Note: I am already using marker clustering.

Note: This problem occurs only on some Motorola and LG devices. In most devices works fine.
Some code:

```
public class OwnRendring extends DefaultClusterRenderer<MyItem> {

    public OwnRendring(Context context, GoogleMap map, ClusterManager<MyItem> clusterManager) {
        super(context, map, clusterManager);
    }

    protected void onBeforeClusterItemRendered(MyItem item, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {

        markerOptions.snippet(item.getSnippet());
        markerOptions.title(item.getTitle());
        markerOptions.anchor(0.33f, 1f);
        markerOptions.infoWindowAnchor(0.33f,0f);

            int cor;
            if (item.getPublico()) {
                cor=cfgCorPostoPublico;
            } else {
                cor=cfgCorPostoPrivado;
            }

            String preço = item.getTitle().substring(item.getTitle().length() - 5);
            if (Objects.equals(preço, "0,000")) { preço=""; }

            Bitmap bitmap = createStoreMarker(preço, cor);
            markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap));

        super.onBeforeClusterItemRendered(item, markerOptions);
    }

    protected boolean shouldRenderAsCluster(Cluster cluster) {
        // if markers < cfgClusterMin then not clustering
        return cfgCluster && cluster.getSize() >= cfgClusterMin;
    }
}

private Bitmap createStoreMarker(String text, int color) {
    View markerLayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_marker, null);

    ImageView markerImage = (ImageView) markerLayout.findViewById(R.id.marker_image);
    TextView markerRating = (TextView) markerLayout.findViewById(R.id.marker_text);
    markerImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.pin_shadow);
    markerImage.clearColorFilter();
    markerImage.getDrawable().mutate().setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY );
    markerRating.setText(text);

    markerLayout.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
    markerLayout.layout(0, 0, markerLayout.getMeasuredWidth(), markerLayout.getMeasuredHeight());

    final Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(markerLayout.getMeasuredWidth(), markerLayout.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    markerLayout.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: has someone any suggest for this issue ? i´m really bugged with this issue...

Comment: refer this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36842011/android-creating-bitmapdescriptor-exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36842011/android-creating-bitmapdescriptor-exception)