# Google maps Could not allocate dup blob fd

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin, markerclusterer

After a lot of attempts to solve this bug,i truly out of ideas what to do,i am understand from what it come from,the cache out of memory.
So after reading some solution here the best one that really improve the performance and provide the app to survive more than 20 seconds was this one:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36903036/9753681

I have more than 30k clusters in the map with icon text that every cluster is a a view.
So what id i inherited `IconGenerator` and create my own cache with `LruCache`,
and by the bounds of the camera i am delete the cluster itself from the `ClusterManger` and the bitmap itself from the cache and save the model itelf of the cluster only in another cache for providing if the camera move and cluster not in the cache of the bitmaps it will be provided by the remove model cache.
In addition just when the camera stop to move i am drawing the cluster.
But still it doesnt work,and it still get the same error :

```
Could not allocate dup blob fd
```

Hers is my code:

**CustomClusterMarker:**

```
    class CustomClusterMarker(private var context: Context,
                          private var map: GoogleMap,
                          private var clusterManager: ClusterManager<ClusterMarkerBase>,
                          clusters: List<ClusterMarkerBase>) :
        DefaultClusterRenderer<ClusterMarkerBase>(context, map, clusterManager) {



    private val TAG: String = CustomClusterMarker::class.simpleName.toString()

    private var mIconGenerator: CachedIconGenerator
    private var mClusterIconGenerator: CachedIconGenerator
    private var bounds: LatLngBounds? = null
    private var isNotMove = true


    init {
        mDimension = context.resources.getDimension(R.dimen.custom_profile_image).toInt()
        mIconGenerator = CachedIconGenerator(context)
        mClusterIconGenerator = CachedIconGenerator(context)
        mIconGenerator.setBackground(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
        mClusterIconGenerator.setBackground(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))

    }


    override fun onBeforeClusterItemRendered(item: ClusterMarkerBase?, markerOptions: MarkerOptions?) {
        //For single item

        if (item == null && markerOptions == null)
            return

//        // Prepare View
        val itemCluster = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.view_marker, null)
        val imgItem = itemCluster.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.image)
        val imgStatus = itemCluster.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.status_icon)
        val tvCount = itemCluster.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txt_counter)
        val txtDescription = itemCluster.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.description_marker)
        imgItem.setImageResource(item!!.mIcon)
        txtDescription.text = item.title

        if (tvCount.visibility == View.VISIBLE)
            tvCount.visibility = View.GONE

        if (imgStatus.visibility == View.GONE)
            imgStatus.visibility = View.VISIBLE

        if (item.isTech) {
            imgStatus.setImageResource(getIconOnCall(item.onCall, imgStatus))
        } else {
            imgStatus.setImageResource(getIconOpenCall(item.onCall, imgStatus))
        }


  //Start cleaning cache before set the icon

        if (bounds != null) {
            if (!bounds!!.contains(item.position)) {
                Completable.fromAction({
                    mIconGenerator.removeIcon(item.mId)
                    mIconGenerator.saveBeforeRemoveCluster(item)
                    clusterManager.removeItem(item)
                }).doOnError {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Show error single remove: " + it.toString())
                }
            }
        }


        if (bounds != null) {
            //Adding the cluster that were delete depends by the bounds
            mIconGenerator.getRemovesClusters(bounds!!)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe({
                        clusterManager.addItems(it)
                    }) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Show add single error: " + it.toString())
                    }
        }

        if (isNotMove) {
            //Convert view to Bitmap and set it on the map with the marker option
            try {
                mIconGenerator.setContentView(itemCluster)
                val descriptorFactory = BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .fromBitmap(mIconGenerator.makeIcon(item.mId))
                markerOptions!!.icon(descriptorFactory)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Show single exeption: " + e.toString())
            }
        }
    }


    override fun onBeforeClusterRendered(cluster: Cluster<ClusterMarkerBase>?, markerOptions: MarkerOptions?) {

        //Check for cluster and mark option is Null
        //For group only!!!!
        if (cluster == null || markerOptions == null)
            return

//        // Inflate View
        val itemCluster = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.view_marker, null)
        val tvCount = itemCluster.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txt_counter)
        val imgItem = itemCluster.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.image)
        val imgStatus = itemCluster.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.status_icon)

        if (imgStatus.visibility == View.VISIBLE)
            imgStatus.visibility = View.GONE

        if (tvCount.visibility == View.GONE)
            tvCount.visibility = View.VISIBLE

        if (cluster.items.isNotEmpty())
            imgItem.setImageResource(cluster.items.first().mIcon)

        tvCount.text = (cluster.size - 1).toString()

        //Convert view to Bitmap and set it on the map with the marker option

        //Start cleaning cache before set the icon

        if (bounds != null) {
            if (!bounds!!.contains(cluster.position)) {
                Completable.fromAction({
                    mClusterIconGenerator.removeIcon(cluster.toString())
                    mClusterIconGenerator.saveBeforeRemoveCluster(cluster.items)
                    for (item in cluster.items) {
                        clusterManager.removeItem(item)
                    }
                }).doOnError {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Show group error remove: " + it.toString())
                }
            }
        }
        //Adding all clusters that were delete depends by the bounds
        if (bounds != null) {
            mClusterIconGenerator.getRemovesClusters(bounds!!)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe({
                        clusterManager.addItems(it)
                    }) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Show group error add: " + it.toString())
                    }
        }

        if (isNotMove) {
            try {
                mClusterIconGenerator.setContentView(itemCluster)
                val descriptorFactory = BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .fromBitmap(mClusterIconGenerator.makeIcon(cluster.toString()))
                markerOptions.icon(descriptorFactory)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e(TAG,"Show gourp exeption: "+e.toString())
            }
        }
    }

    fun setBounds(bounds: LatLngBounds) {
        this.bounds = bounds
    }

    fun setOnCameraState(isNotMove: Boolean) {
        this.isNotMove = isNotMove
    }

    override fun shouldRenderAsCluster(cluster: Cluster<ClusterMarkerBase>?): Boolean {
        return super.shouldRenderAsCluster(cluster)
    }

    private fun getIconOnCall(isOnCall: Boolean, image: ImageView): Int {
        return if (isOnCall) {
            image.visibility = View.GONE
            0
        } else {
            image.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            R.drawable.free
        }
    }

    private fun getIconOpenCall(onCall: Boolean, image: ImageView): Int {
        return if (onCall) {
            image.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            R.drawable.open_call
        } else {
            image.visibility = View.GONE
            0
        }
    }
```

My own custom cache:

**CachedIconGenerator:**

```
    class CachedIconGenerator(context: Context) : IconGenerator(context) {

    private val mBitmapsCache: LruCache<String, Bitmap>
    private val mModelClusterCache: LruCache<String, ClusterMarkerBase>
    private var bounds: LatLngBounds? = null

    private val TAG = CachedIconGenerator::class.simpleName

    init {

        val maxMemory = (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024).toInt()

        // Use 1/8th of the available memory for this memory cache.
        val cacheSize = maxMemory / 8
        mBitmapsCache = object : LruCache<String, Bitmap>(cacheSize) {
            override fun sizeOf(key: String, bitmap: Bitmap): Int {
                // The cache size will be measured in kilobytes rather than
                // number of items.
                return bitmap.byteCount / 1024
            }
        }
//        val sizeModel = maxMemory
        mModelClusterCache = LruCache(cacheSize)

    }

    fun saveBeforeRemoveCluster(cluster: ClusterMarkerBase) {
        mModelClusterCache.put(cluster.mId, cluster)
    }

    fun saveBeforeRemoveCluster(clusters: Collection<ClusterMarkerBase>) {
        for (item in clusters) {
            mModelClusterCache.put(item.mId, item)
        }
    }

    fun setBounds(bounds: LatLngBounds) {
        this.bounds = bounds
    }

    fun removeIcon(id: String) {
        if (mBitmapsCache[id] != null)
            mBitmapsCache.remove(id)
    }

    fun isIconExsit(id: String): Boolean {
        return mBitmapsCache[id] != null
    }

    fun makeIcon(id: String): Bitmap? {
        return if (mBitmapsCache[id] == null) {
            val bitmap = super.makeIcon()
            mBitmapsCache.put(id, bitmap)
            bitmap
        } else
            mBitmapsCache[id]

    }

    fun getRemovesClusters(bounds: LatLngBounds): Observable<ArrayList<ClusterMarkerBase>> {
        val list = ArrayList<ClusterMarkerBase>()
        for (item in mModelClusterCache.snapshot().values) {
            if (bounds.contains(item.position))
                list.add(item)
        }
        return Observable.just(list)

    }

    fun isCacheEmtpty(): Boolean {
        return mBitmapsCache.size() == 0
    }

}
```

Comment: No one can help me with this problem ? :(

Comment: You are not alone my friend. i'm also facing the same issue :(